# Python requests session times out on Travis but not locally

Tags: python, python-requests, travis-ci

I'm running into a strange issue where my tests are passing locally, but failing on TravisCI.

I am importing a class from a third party library whose behavior I need to alter slightly, so I am using `unittest.mock.patch` to patch it. Specifically, I am using an object that has as one of it's class properties a "connection manager" that handles GET/POST/PUT to a remote address. This connection manager has as one of it's properties a `requests.Session` object, and this is what I need to patch out.

I need to mount a new `HTTPAdapter` to the `requests.Session` object at the time of creation of the object, which I do like so:

```
class CustomAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
  def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
      num_pools=connections,
      maxsize=maxsize,
      block=block,
      assert_hostname=False)

def custom_session_function():
  session = requests.Session()
  session.mount(CustomHttpAdapter())
  return session

def my_function():
  with patch('somemodule.requests.Session', return_value=custom_session_function()):
    return SomeClass()
```

All the `CustomHttpAdapter` is doing is inheriting from `HTTPAdapter` and creating `PoolManager` with `assert_hostname=False` (this is to use SSL connection with a private ca)

I have a bunch of unit tests that use methods on the `SomeClass` object that involve sending out HTTP requests. They are simply using the `requests.Session` object and doing `session.post` and so on.

Sample class method:

```
def do_post(self, path, **kwargs):
  return self.session.get(
    path,
    params=kwargs,
    headers=self.headers,
    timeout=self.timeout,
    verify=self.verify)
```

All of these pass just fine when I run them locally, but when I submit the PR to Travis, the job will fail when it gets to the first test that communicates with the server (which is running on travis locally in a docker container)

They always complain about a timeout in the error:

```
virtualenv/lib/python3.6/http/client.py:266: in _read_status raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without response"`
E   http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

I'm pretty stumped as the error is not very descriptive. Even more perplexing, attaching to the Travis build in debug mode, and manually running the function that just failed seems to work fine. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm not sure if its down to the way I'm patching this object, or the Custom adapter itself.

EDIT: Additional information. The issue appears to be more or less random. In the debugging build, I can run the same function multiple times, and sometimes it will work, and sometimes it will not. The tests pass consistently if I don't try to mount the custom adapter. I changed the poolmanager to allow multiple retries of each request, and was able to get the build to pass once, but this is not a durable solution and results in intermittent, random failures of builds.

EDIT2: Even more strangely, just patching and returning an unmodified requests.Session object seems to create more problems than mounting the custom adapter.

```
def custom_session_function():
  return requests.Sesssion()
```

Causes the timeout to occur on the first request, rather than after a few requests.